# Solving a Definite Integral of a Quadratic Polynomial Satisfying Three Constraints

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

> **Question** If $f(x)$ a quadratic polynomial
>   such that $f(0)=2$, $f'(0)=-3,$ and $f''(0)=4$, find
>   $$\int_{-1}^{1}f\left(x\right)dx.$$

**My Approach** Using the given derivative $\frac{f\left(h\right)-2}{h}$=-3
and$\frac{f'\left(h\right)+3}{h}=$4 $\Longrightarrow$$f\left(x\right)=\frac{-3}{4}f'\left(x\right)-\frac{9}{4}+2$

$\Longrightarrow$$\int_{-1}^{1}f\left(x\right)dx=-\frac{3}{2}\left[f\left(1\right)-f\left(0\right)\right]-\frac{9}{2}+4$.
But still I don't know the value of $f\left(1\right)$.
I may be wrong but i just felt that f(x) is even

Comment: impressed .. you first tried yourself then asked for a hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quadratic polynomial $p(x)\in \mathbf{R}[x]$ is of the form $p(x)=Ax^2+Bx+C$. We know that $2=p(0)=C$. So, with this datum, we have that our polynomial looks like 
$$ p(x)=Ax^2+Bx+2.$$
$p'(x)=2Ax+B$. Now, $-3=p'(0)=B$ so that $B=-3$. Our polynomial is thus of the form
$$ p(x)=Ax^2-3x+2.$$
$p''(x)=2A$. So, we have that $4=p''(0)=2A$. Therefore, $A=2$. So, our polynomial is 
$$ p(x)=2x^2-3x+2.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes! For sure Thanks Brother

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You're ignoring the fact that you are told $f$ is a quadratic polynomial. The three conditions determine $f$ exactly.

Suppose $f(x)=ax^2 + bx+c$, so that $f'(x)=2ax + b$ and $f''(x) = 2a$.

Then $$2=f(0)=c$$ $$-3=f'(0)=b$$ $$4=f''(0)=2a$$

You should be able to write down $f$ exactly now and integrate it with no problem.

Comment: Yes i am. I just took the wrong way

Comment: @Should i complete the answer in the question after determining the f

Comment: Yes, getting $f$ is only part of it. They want you to (1) determine $f$, then (2) compute the integral of the $f$ you found. So the final answer is some single number.